# Reclassify raster based on Z-values in Arcmap 10.4.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.4, reclassify

I have a raster which has a Z-value applied to each pixel. I want to reclassify the raster so that any pixels with values below 1 are removed. Is there an ArcMap tool which can perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered this myself, the Reclassify tool under 3D Analyst tools - Raster Reclass allows you to redefine the values of a range of pixels. I set one of the classes as 0-1 and set the new values to 'NoData'. The resulting output created the raster without any pixel values below 1.

Comment: That will work, there are other solutions as well. FYI, this operation isn't a 'clip', clipping usually means erasing everything outside of a certain 2D boundary from your original layer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at the "Set Null" tool if you are hoping to keep all other raster values intact but remove those < 1.